# Compute determinant of binary NxN matrix by cuda

Tags: math, parallel-processing, cuda, gpu

I'm looking for a good approach to compute the determinant of a binary NxN matrix.

So far I found this: https://github.com/OrangeOwlSolutions/Linear-Algebra/blob/master/DETERMINANT/determinant.cu, but this implementation may be good for general matrix (floating point) while I only need to work with integers. Also, cuBLAS or cuSOLVER only support double-precision matrices.

Comment: If your integers are 32-bit integers, then using `double` quantities (53 bits of mantissa) may still be workable.  Depending on the GPU, that may be the fastest way.  Some GPUs have double-precision floating point throughput that is "close" to integer throughput.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I think there's a trick to do LU decomposition on binary matrices, then we can easily compute det from LU, but I'm still looking for it.

Comment: [this](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82518786.pdf) may be of interest

Comment: What do you actually mean by binary? That all the entries are either 1 or 0, or something else?

Comment: @talonmies yes, only 0 and 1

Comment: How large is the N?

Comment: currently, I only need N=64, but it needs to be fast, under 1ms

Comment: **The hunt for an E2E solution <`1[ms]` @`x[GHz]` Device just started**.A most compact data-representation in but 64 `int64`-s may look tempting,yet all add-on costs (`h2d`+`d2h` transfers) & a design of a SIMD/SM efficient processing **decide** here,not the densest ever representation(which can't be cheaply de-composed,the less natively processed on silicon) **Measure** &straight **`SUB`** from the `1[ms]` target **`{h2d+d2h}`**-latencies+XFER-durations for async moves of the said 512B data,remainder **`DIV`** by the `x` to see instructions left for any SM-aligned GPU-computing… **Feasible?**

Comment: I have answered this based on some mathematical musing regarding the properties of binary matrices and their determinants. I doubt there is a useful native integer way to do this safely without overflow at the size you asked about. You would need to use double precision floating point and live with the cost and approximate nature. For very small matrices it might well be possible to do a modulo-2 arithmetic implementation on the GPU

Answer (score 2):

According to [this reference](http://oeis.org/A003432), there is a known upper-bound for the determinant of a [square (0,1)-matrix](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/01-Matrix.html) of rank N.

For N=36, the upper bound determinate is given as 1200757082375992968, which requires 61 integer bits for exact representation. Given that the GPU only has native integer types up to 64 bit in length, there is absolutely no way this could be done for N=64 in integer without some sort of big integer implementation (if it existed), and that would be a 100% software implementation and guaranteed to be very slow.

Therefore, the only feasible implementation would be performed in double precision floating point, and one of the existing double precision linear algebra libraries would be the optimal (and only) feasible solution on a GPU.